# GORM converts query text into lowercase

Tags: go, grails-orm, go-gorm

```
response := db.Where("createdAt BETWEEN ? AND ?", today, tomorrow).Find(&orders)
```

I want to make a query with GORM. The column in my table is named "createdAt" but GORM converts it to. "createdat"

```
    ERROR: column "createdat" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703)
[172.521ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "Orders" WHERE `createdAt` BETWEEN '2021-04-21 04:00:00' AND '2021-04-22 04:00:00'
```

How can I prevent GORM from converting the query text to lowercase?

Comment: Check out this [table](https://seeq.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KB/pages/443088907/SQL+Column+Names+and+Case+Sensitivity) on case sensitivity for different DBs.

Comment: Hey guys I solved using this: response := db.Where(" \"createdAt\" BETWEEN ? AND ?", today, tomorrow).Find(&orders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not gorm's issue its database issue means in database column is created with name `created_at` just check there and try replacing your code with this

```
response := db.Where("created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", today, tomorrow).Find(&orders)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use case sensitive column name, use `\"`,ex: `\"createdAt\"`, No modern database cannot handle upper or lower case text.